# fprintf not giving the values expected

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to read numbers from multiple text files starting with 'numbers' and calculate the sum. I am getting some random numbers not contained in the file I am opening. I have tried initializing the array at 0 but that just made everything 0 on output.
This is the problem section I believe

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
DIR *d;
struct dirent *dir;
int fileAndSum(){
int sum = 0, i = 0;
int nums[100];
FILE* fptr = fopen(dir->d_name,"r");
 fputs("11111111111111111", fptr);
for(i = 0; i <10; i++){
  fscanf(fptr,"%d", &nums[i]);
  printf("%d\n", nums[i]);
  sum+=nums[i];
}
printf("%s\n", "----------sum--------------");
printf("%d\n", sum);
fclose(fptr);
```

The rest

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
DIR *d;
struct dirent *dir;
int fileAndSum(){
int sum = 0, i = 0;
int nums[100];
FILE* fptr = fopen(dir->d_name,"r");
for(i = 0; i <10; i++){
  fscanf(fptr,"%d", &nums[i]);
  printf("%d\n", nums[i]);
  sum+=nums[i];
}
printf("%s\n", "----------sum--------------");
printf("%d\n", sum);
fclose(fptr);

}
int main(void) {
  d = opendir("numdir");
  char strhold[50] = "numbers";
  char fileName[50];
    while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
      if(strstr(dir->d_name, strhold)){
        printf("%s%s%s\n", "----------Now reading ",dir->d_name,"--------------");
        fileAndSum();
        printf("%s\n", "----------Next file--------------");
      }
    }
    closedir(d);

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: Why do you open the file for **reading** (`fptr = fopen(dir->d_name,"r")`) and immediately try to **write** something there (`fputs("11111111111111111", fptr)`)?

Comment: You need to check if `fopen` fails and act accordingly, e.g. display an error message and abort. Same for `opendir`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your files to read are in directory `numdir`, but you are trying to read files in current working directory.

Also you should check if file open is successful.

to fix, the part

```
FILE* fptr = fopen(dir->d_name,"r");
```

should be

```
char fileName[1024];
snprintf(fileName, sizeof(fileName), "numdir/%s", dir->d_name);
FILE* fptr = fopen(fileName,"r");
if(fptr == NULL){
  puts("open failed");
  return 0;
}
```